# Making a customizable LCG that travels backward and forward

Tags: random, procedural-generation, lcg

How would i go about making an LCG (type of pseudo random number generator) travel in both directions?
I know that travelling forward is `(a*x+c)%m` but how would i be able to reverse it? 
I am using this so i can store the seed at the position of the player in a map and be able to generate things around it by propogating backward and forward in the LCG (like some sort of randomized number line).

Comment: The whole idea of PRNGs (as opposed to any random numeric sequence) is to be non-reversible. Indeed, the modulus operation is a simple example of "many to one" function, which precludes reversibility by the very definition.

Comment: By reversible do mean for a given seed & index, find the random number for the same seed that would have come at (index-1)?

Comment: You should accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All LCGs cycle.  In an LCG which achieves maximal cycle length there is a unique predecessor and a unique successor for each value x (which won't necessarily be true for LCGs that don't achieve maximal cycle length, or for other algorithms with subcycle behaviors such as von Neumann's [middle-square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method)).

Suppose our LCG has cycle length L.  Since the behavior is cyclic, that means that after L iterations we are back to the starting value.  Finding the predecessor value by taking one step backwards is mathematically equivalent to taking (L-1) steps forward.

The big question is whether that can be converted into a single step. If you're using a Prime Modulus Multiplicative LCG (where the additive constant is zero), it turns out to be pretty easy to do.  If x<sub>i+1</sub> = a * x<sub>i</sub> % m, then x<sub>i+n</sub> = a<sup>n</sup> * x<sub>i</sub> % m.  As a concrete example, consider the PMMLCG with a = 16807 and m = 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  This has a maximal cycle length of m-1 (it can never yield 0 for obvious reasons), so our goal is to iterate m-2 times.  We can precalculate a<sup>m-2</sup> % m = 1407677000 using readily available exponentiation/mod libraries. Consequently, a forward step is found as x<sub>i+1</sub> = 16807 * x<sub>i</sub> % 2<sup>31</sup>-1, while a backwards step is found as x<sub>i-1</sub> = 1407677000 * x<sub>i</sub> % 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

---

**ADDITIONAL**

The same concept can be extended to generic full-cycle LCGs by casting the transition in matrix form and doing fast matrix exponentiation to come up with the equivalent one-stage transform. The matrix formulation for x<sub>i+1</sub> = (a * x<sub>i</sub> + c) % m is X<sub>i+1</sub> = T · X<sub>i</sub> % m, where T is the matrix `[[a c],[0 1]]` and X is the column vector (x, 1) transposed. Multiple iterations of the LCG can be quickly calculated by raising T to any desired power through fast exponentiation techniques using squaring and halving the power. After noticing that powers of matrix T never alter the second row, I was able to focus on just the first row calculations and produced the following implementation in Ruby:

```
def power_mod(ary, mod, power)
  return ary.map { |x| x % mod } if power < 2
  square = [ary[0] * ary[0] % mod, (ary[0] + 1) * ary[1] % mod]
  square = power_mod(square, mod, power / 2)
  return square if power.even?
  return [square[0] * ary[0] % mod, (square[0] * ary[1] + square[1]) % mod]
end
```

where `ary` is a vector containing a and c, the multiplicative and additive coefficients.

Using this with `power` set to the cycle length - 1, I was able to determine coefficients which yield the predecessor for [various LCGs listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use). For example, to "reverse" the LCG with a = 1664525, c = 1013904223, and m = 2<sup>32</sup>, use a = 4276115653 and c = 634785765.  You can easily confirm that the latter set of coefficients reverses the sequence produced by using the original coefficients.

Comment: You should write a book about pseudo-random number generation if you did not already.

Comment: Thanks, but it's already been done by much smarter people than me.  Also, books are a big investment of time and effort and based on the voting here I suspect it wouldn't sell very many copies.

Comment: You sure would not do it for the money :D