# How to Generate a 'Future-Index' Pseudo-Random Number Without Generating Its Preceding Numbers

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

**Context:**

Let's consider a random-number set of `10` `integer` elements generated by one of the [PRNG-C++ approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c) using a fixed seed integer, i.e. `const int seedMe = 31`:

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

**Question:**

Assuming pseudo-random number generators generate fixed number sequences, which are determined by the seed.

- For the known seed (`seedMe`) and the known set size (`10`), is it **conceptually** possible to generate the random number corresponding to the index `N` in advance? For example, generation of the `3`rd element of the above set without generating the preceding `0 1 2`.
- If so, is there any **practical** example of such practice in C++?

**Aim of the Question:**

For known `seed` and `set size`, in my parallel computations, a 1-D random-number global-set is needed, which should be the same for each processor.

Each processor uses a subset of the global-set, and accordingly, *a priori* knows the global-set **indices** for the subset. For example, for a 2-processor computation, the first processor needs only `i = [0, 4]` indexed-random numbers, and the second proc `i = [5, 9]` indexed ones.

I wonder if we can *directly* and *locally* generate the subsets of a global-PRNG set at each processor, hence the discard of any need for parallel communication of any sort.

Comment: Won't a good (seedable) hash-function solve this problem? Just hash each index...

Comment: Your question is pretty darn broad, but you might be able to modify or extend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078247/2166798) to a broader class of generators than LCGs.  The trick would be to come up with a matrix representation of the generator's state transformation, after which you could take any arbitrary power of the matrix to advance that many iterations of the generator.